# What is the difference between lm() function and caret::train() function when it comes to creating linear regression models?

Tags: r, regression, machine-learning, caret

When applying the `lm` function as follows (the assumptions were not considered. The purpose of this example is just to make my question clear) :

```r
library(carData)

model1 = lm(data = carData::Salaries,salary~sex+yrs.service+yrs.since.phd)
```

and comparing it with the model created with the function `caret::train()` (method = "lm") :

```
library(caret)

mycontrol = trainControl(method = "CV",number=10,)

model2 = train(salary~sex+yrs.service+yrs.since.phd,
               data = Salaries,
               method = "lm",
               trControl=mycontrol)
```

The outcomes of the two models are the same. why ?

```
summary(model1)
summary(model2)
```

Comment: The answer to your question lies in the implementation of the caret package and what is shown to the user in the summary method.  This is likely a question for the caret package maintainers.